# mvc3 decimal is rounding 2 places

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, decimal

I have a model that takes in latitudes and longitudes but for some reason when the model is created it keeps rounding the latitude/longitude to 2 decimal places instead of saving the whole value for instance this -81.39522999999997 is saved as -81.39000000000000  how can I fix this?

my model is

```
public decimal? longit { get; set; }
```

the view is

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.longit, new {@Value = "-81.39522999999997" })
```

and my MSSQL for this is saved as 
longit Decimal(16,14)

and quick question 16,14 means 2 digits to the left and 14 to the right if I have a longitude of 103.39522999999997 would it cost an error? since it would be (16,13) this is my first time working with decimals..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hey everyone i learned how to do it..in case you ever think about doing it

1. you need to go to your Context class where you initialize your entity tables ..

   public DbSet relistings { get; set; } look similar to that then you write this code

   ```
   public class mycontext : DbContext
   {
   public DbSet<relisting> relistings { get; set; }
   //this is the code you write
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<relisting>().Property(x => x.latit).HasPrecision(16, 14);
       modelBuilder.Entity<relisting>().Property(x => x.longit).HasPrecision(16, 14);

   }
   //ends here
      }
   ```

the **relisting** is the name of the model the decimal is in then offcourse the x=>x.mydecimal is the decimal property you want then with has precision you put in how accurate you want things to be.. works liks a charm

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used entity framework which translated it to decimal (from SQL Server `Decimal(9,6)` as this seems to be up to 0.1m.

latitude/longitude doesn't need anywhere near the precision of double.

At any rate I was able to combat MVC here by putting a `DisplayFormatAttribute` on my latitude/longitude properties:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = {0:0.######})]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) instead of [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) if you need this kind of precision:

```
public double? longit { get; set; }
```

Decimal's for money, double's for science. Since you are doing science here (calculating latitude and longitude) and not dealing with money, you'd better use the correct data type.

Comment: Not so according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.100).aspx).  `decimal` is suitable whenever 28-digit precision (and range) with minimal rounding errors is required.

Comment: i think Darins pointing out that decimal is 2 decimal places if its meant for $$$.

Comment: @DaveA - My compiler must be broken: `decimal foo = 1m / 7m; -- Result: 0.1428571428571428571428571429M`.  The OP may have an output formatting problem, but `decimal` is up to the task.

Comment: then id say an html markup hidden would be better. HiddenFor has a tendancy to format its data to expected types.

Comment: "Decimals for money, doubles for science" I can't get over how wrong this sentence is. Decimal is for when high, accurate, high precision is required, and you're worried about compound errors. Double just when high precision is required at small quantities; The bigger a double gets, the more it loses all precision. A decimal maintains it's precision regardless of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but this confused me too for a while when updated currency exchange rates were saved to the database with only 2 decimal places (which, it turns out, is the default). I use model mapping for entities which can be set like this:-

```
public class CurrencyMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Currency>
{
    public CurrencyMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
        // .HasPrecision(precision, scale)
        // 'precision' is the total number of digits the db will store,
        // regardless of where the decimal point falls 
        // 'scale' is the number of decimal places that will be stored
        Property(x => x.Rate).IsRequired().HasPrecision(16, 6);
    }
}
```